# CakePHP model validation with array

Tags: validation, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I want to use CakePHP's core validation for lists in my model:

```
var $validate = array(
  'selectBox' => array(
    'allowedChoice' => array(
        'rule' => array('inList', $listToCheck),
        'message' => 'Enter something in listToCheck.'
    )
  )
);
```

However, the `$listToCheck` array is the same array that's used in the view, to populate a selectbox. Where do I put this function?

```
public function getList() {
    return array('hi'=>'Hello','bi'=>'Goodbye','si'=>'Salutations');
}
```

Already in my controller, in one of the actions I'm setting it for the view, like:

```
public function actionForForm() {
    $options = $this->getList();
    $this->set('options', $options);
}
```

So, I don't want to have to copy the `getList()` function...where can I put it so the Model can call it to populate its `$listToCheck` array?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering that it's data, you should store the list of valid choices in the model.

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    var $fieldAbcChoices = array('a' => 'The A', 'b' => 'The B', 'c' => 'The C');

}
```

You can get that variable in the Controller simply like this:

```
$this->set('fieldAbcs', $this->MyModel->fieldAbcChoices);
```

Unfortunately you can't simply use that variable in the rule declaration for the `inList` rule, since rules are declared as instance variables and those can only be initialized statically (no variables allowed). The best way around that is to set the variable in the Constructor:

```
var $validate = array(
    'fieldAbc' => array(
        'allowedChoice' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array()),
            'message' => 'Enter something in listToCheck.'
        )
    )
);

function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->validate['fieldAbc']['allowedChoice']['rule'][1] = array_keys($this->fieldAbcChoices);
}
```

If you're not comfortable overriding the Constructor, you could also do this in a `beforeValidate()` callback.

Also note that you shouldn't name your field 'selectBox'. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But what happens when I want to use the `__()` function on the fieldAbc values?

Comment: Then create the whole array in the constructor, or `array_walk` over it and apply the function on `message` fields. `$this->choices = array('a' => __('The A', true), …);`